# > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' UnsupportedMajor version64

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I want to update my Gerdle version and I encounter this error. This problem was created in Flutter 3.13.

Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.